# How can I make nginx reverse proxy for localhost when connectd with IP address?

Tags: nginx, ssl, localhost, nginx-reverse-proxy

I made reverse proxy on my nginx like this

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;

    return 301 https://[my domein]$request_uri;

}
```

this works well, when I access **http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/index.html**.
My nginx redirect to https://[my domain]/index.html

But, when I access **https://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/index.html** Chrome shows “Your connection is not private” error.
Self-signed certificates do not help avoid this error. A CA-signed certificate is required.
In this case, how do I get the SSL certificate for localhost? It is **localhost**. No one could issue a localhost certificate, I think.

Does anyone know a good way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Use mkcert.**

**Install mkcert**

```
sudo apt install libnss3-tools
```

Check mkcert releases page for the [latest version](https://github.com/FiloSottile/mkcert/releases). As of this writing, the latest release is.v1.4.3

```
export VER="v1.4.3"
wget -O mkcert https://github.com/FiloSottile/mkcert/releases/download/${VER}/mkcert-${VER}-linux-amd64
chmod +x mkcert
sudo mv mkcert /usr/local/bin
```

**Install certificate**
generate locally trusted SSL certificates

```
mkcert -install
ls -1 ~/.local/share/mkcert
mkdir ~/cert && cd ~/cert
mkcert crm.site '*.crm.site' localhost 127.0.0.1 ::1
```

**Add to nginx**

```
sudo nano /etc/nginx/sites-available/crm.site
```

```
server {
   listen *:443 ssl http2;
   index index.php;
   root /home/andrey/crm.site;
   server_name crm.site *.crm.site;

   ssl_certificate /home/andrey/cert/crm.site+4.pem;
   ssl_certificate_key /home/andrey/cert/crm.site+4-key.pem;

        client_max_body_size 128M;
        client_body_buffer_size 128k;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
                add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubdomains" always;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
                include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
        }
}
```

and restart nginx

```
sudo service nginx restart
```

Comment: Thank you for your information. I will try mkcert.